# How to use AWS_IAM authorization for AppSync using a custom domain?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-appsync

I would like to use [AWS_IAM authorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authz.html#aws-iam-authorization) to connect to AppSync from backends (Lambda/Fargate) but it does not appear to work with [AppSync Custom Domains](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/custom-domain-name.html).

I have implemented AppSync using a custom domain (see [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/custom-domain-name.html) and [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/mobile/introducing-custom-domain-names-for-aws-appsync-apis/)).

This works fine from browsers clients using [AWS_LAMBDA authorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authz.html#aws-lambda-authorization).

However, attempting to use [AWS_IAM authorization](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/security-authz.html#aws-iam-authorization) from backends (Lambda/Fargate) does not work for me all.

I have needed to revert to utilising the "non-custom" URLs (e.g. `https://example123.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql`) to get AWS_IAM authorization to work.

Has anyone had a different experience?